# Venn diagram either using R or matlab?

Tags: matlab, venn-diagram

I am a newbie in coding and want a venn diagram that shows the relation of the sum of two columns (Score1 and Score 2 vs nasanov 1 and nasanov 2) that only contains 0 and 1. Also I'm interested in create one diagram per group and treatment.

| Group | Treatment | bee_1 | Nasanov bee_1 | bee_2 | nasanov 2 |

Thanks :)

in R I have tried this, but I basically do not know what I am doing. Name of the columns is right

count_lists <- list()

```
# Loop a través de tratamientos y grupos únicos
count_lists <- list()

# Loop a través de tratamientos y grupos únicos
for (treatment in unique(data$treatment)) {
  for (grupo in unique(data$group)) {
    subset_data <- data[data$treatment == treatment & data$group == grupo, ]
    count_0000 <- sum(subset_data$bee_1 == 0 & subset_data$bee_2 == 0 & subset_data$`Nasanov bee_1` == 0 & subset_data$`nasanov bee_2` == 0)
    count_0001 <- sum(subset_data$bee_1 == 0 & subset_data$bee_2 == 0 & subset_data$`Nasanov bee_1` == 0 & subset_data$`nasanov bee_2` == 1)
    count_0010 <- sum(subset_data$bee_1 == 0 & subset_data$bee_2 == 0 & subset_data$`Nasanov bee_1` == 1 & subset_data$`nasanov bee_2` == 0)
    count_0011 <- sum(subset_data$bee_1 == 0 & subset_data$bee_2 == 0 & subset_data$`Nasanov bee_1` == 1 & subset_data$`nasanov bee_2` == 1)
    # ... y así sucesivamente para todas las combinaciones posibles
    
    count_lists[[paste(treatment, grupo)]] <- c(count_0000, count_0001, count_0010, count_0011)
  }
}

# Crear el diagrama de Venn
venn.plot <- venn.diagram(
  x = count_lists,
  category.names = c("bee_1", "bee_2", "Nasanov bee_1", "nasanov bee_2"),
  filename = NULL
)

# Mostrar el diagrama de Venn
grid.draw(venn.plot)
```

Comment: For MATLAB you might want to check out this [File Exchange: Venn Diagram](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/120118-venn-diagram)